# How can I design reusable code in function for testing in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, function, testing, puppeteer

I code test in puppeteer with jest:

How to create reusable function for similar login tests without code repeating?

```
  describe('new user test', () => {
    test('no existed user try', async() => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions)
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://admin.manager.synthrone.com/") 

  await page.waitForSelector('#mat-input-0')
  await page.type('#mat-input-0', 'test')
  await page.type('#mat-input-1', 'pass')
  await page.click('button')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already written a valid anonymous callback function, you'd just have to parametrize some of the needed variables and give a name to the function.

Here's an example of selectors and url as arguments

```
async function loginTest(url, selectors){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector('#mat-input-0');
    await Promise.all(Object.keys(selectors).map(selector => page.type(selector, selectors[selector])));
    await page.click('button');

    await browser.close();
}

describe('new user test', () => {
    test('no existed user try', () => loginTest("https://admin.manager.synthrone.com/", {'#mat-input-0': 'test', '#mat-input-1': 'pass'}));
    test('some other test', () => loginTest("https://admin.manager.synthrone.com/", {'#mat-input-0': 'differentarg', '#mat-input-1': 'differentpass'}));
});
```